# Extract value from Object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanted to make a dynamic method in which i pass any instance of object i made, for example:

```
public class Employee()
{
  public string FName;
  public string SName;
  .....etc.
}
```

The method i want is like the following:

```
public void methodName(Object oObject)
{
  //lets say that i have passed object employee to it.
}
```

Is it possible to extract any values from the oObject, i have tried to do so but it have no attributes to do so, and when i put in the watch i can acutally see all the attribute of class employee in it.

So is there any way ?

Comment: Do you want the value of a specific property on each object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>There are many ways.</strike>

**Update:** you say you want the whole object. [Casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or interfaces to expose the properties is the way foward.

You can cast the object to the specific type:

```
if (oObject is Employee)
{
    string name = (oObject as Employee).FName;
}
```

You can expose an interface that defines what the method expects, then provided types implement the interface:

```
public interface IFirstName
{
    string FName { get; }
}

public void methodName(IFirstName objectWithFirstName)
{
    string name = objectWithFirstName.FName;
}
```

You can use `dynamic` and hope for the best at runtime (.NET 4):

```
public void methodName(dynamic oObject)
{
    string name = oObject.FName;
}
```

And then there is reflection.

But the better question to ask is, is this a good method? I would be a little skeptical about methods that take anything and make expectations about things... though that's not to say it doesn't or shouldn't happen.

Comment: What i am trying to achieve, is that instead of creating methods for SqlDataReader for each class, just send the object reference and the procedure name, and return a filled object.

Comment: @user733659 The way I would do that is define an interface that each class implements that the read/write method asks for, so that each object is actually responsible for reading/writing itself. Either that or you use reflection and property names, but this can get a little flakey.

Comment: @user733659 Sorry, that sort of design question is a little larger in scope than this question - post a new SO question about how best to implement a method for generic handling of DAL code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access values by simply type casting object back into Employee class like this

```
  public void methodName(Object oObject)
    {
      //lets say that i have passed object employee to it.
      //if oObject belongs to Employee class
      if(oObject is Employee)
      {
          Employee employee = oObject as Employee;
          //you can get access values here
      }
    }
```

Comment: You should use only `as` and then test employee with null.  `Employee employee = oObject as Employee; if(employee != null) {  }`

Comment: @meziantou Actually the `if (oObject is Employee)` will filter out nulls as a null object reference has no type other than object.